# Is it worth using vdmfec for backups to external SATA/IDE hard drives?

Tags: backup, hard-disk

I have some SATA/IDE hard drive enclosures that I use for backups. The drives for formatted with VFAT, since I need to be able to share them with Windows and OS/X machines.

The backup scripts pipe the output through [vdmfec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/vdmfec.1.html) to provide error correction for the files. (I started doing this when I found that some old backup files were damaged.)

The example on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/vdmfec.1.html) refers to 1.44MB "floppy" discs.

So my question is: is it worth using vdmfec for hard drives (as I've heard that newer ones have built-in error correction)? And if so, should I be using different settings than the defaults?

Also: are there better tools for Linux than vdmfec for error correction?

Comment: Another similar tool: http://dvdisaster.net/en/

Comment: @Wodin Thanks for the ref to another tool, but I don't use DVDs/CDs. (They're just not big enough for my backups.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding Error Correcting Codes (ECC) to your backups is definitely a good thing. You trade off some amount of extra space to gain some robustness in the form of data redundancy.

`vdmfec` looks like a nice little tool. By default, it assumes a block size of b=1024 bytes, and it writes out N=18 blocks for every K=14 blocks of input. This means that by default, the output size is inflated by N-K=4 blocks for every 14 blocks, for a size increase of about 29%. You can play with the parameters K and N to get more or less redundancy, although my feeling is that the defaults are probably okay for most uses.

You need to be aware of a couple of potential gotchas, though. First, according to the man page:

> Note  that  the  N,  K, and blocksize parameters are NOT written to the
>          output!  You must specify the same parameters when you run the decoder.
>          (Actually,  the decoder is capable of explicitly detecting an invalid K
>          value, but incorrect blocksize or N values will result  in  bad  blocks
>          and decode failure.)

So remember to document the particular parameters you use for each of your backups. Even if you always use the defaults, it may be a good idea to explicitly document those values, since defaults can change in newer versions of the program.

Secondly, the man page says this:

> The  decoder  is  capable  of  reading  from non-seekable media such as
>          pipes, however, buffer underruns are not detected and  will  result  in
>          failure.   Also, when reading from a pipe the entire file must be read.
>          Reading from a seek-able stream can  be  faster  because  only  K  good
>          blocks out of N need to be read.

This means that it is best (and safest) to put `vdmfec` last in your command pipeline when creating your backups. E.g.:

```
tar -cf - /data | gzip | vdmfec > /backups/data.tgz.vdm
```

By doing the `vdmfec` encoding last when backing-up, it means you can use the `vdmfec` decoder on a seekable file instead of on a non-seekable pipe when restoring, and thus avoid the potential problems that can arise when using pipes. E.g.:

```
vdmfec_decode /backups/data.tgz.vdm | zcat | tar -xf -
```

In summary, I would say that `vdmfec` is a good tool to use to make your backups more robust against data loss due to errors caused by media degradation. Today's hard drives are using ever higher bit densities to achieve their ever increasing multi-terabyte capacities, so I think it is definitely worth adding some extra redundancy to backups, just for safety.

And finally: Another tool that has a similar function to `vdmfec` is `par2` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/par2.1.html)), but it works in an entirely different way. `par2` may be a more suitable tool if you find you need to `split` your archive files, since `par2` was developed to add ECC to large files split into numerous smaller files (e.g. for posting to USENET binaries groups).

Comment: I pipe the output of vdmfec to split (since files on VFAT are limited to 4GB, and my backups are significantly larger).

Comment: @Rob: In that case, I recommend you look into `par2`. Briefly, `par2` works by running as a post-processing step on your large archive files. It creates a number of files containing redundancy codes that can be used to repair the original files, should they be corrupted. The number and size of the redundancy files is configurable.

Comment: @Steven I don't see what I get from using par2 that I already don't have with vdmfec.

Comment: I've also found another tool, zfec http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zfec though I think it uses the same algorithm as vdmfec

Comment: @Rob: It was just a suggestion. If `vdmfec` works for you, then keep using it! Just be certain that you are able to restore from your backups, when/if the time comes.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the suggestion BTW. I have tested restoring vdmfec piped to split (by catting  them together and decoding). It seems to work. The real "test" will be restoring files from damaged disks, though.